# Is 'grapheme' a substance or a typo?

Tags: terminology, definition, graphene

While reading Ref. 1 I came across the sentence

> *Below we focus on the physics of ideal (single layer) grapheme.*

I did google search 'grapheme' but the results tended towards a completely unrelated use of the word.

When I googled it alongside the word physics I got a number of hits, none of which could exclude the possibility of it being a typo of 'graphene'. Is 'grapheme' a real word?

Bonus points if you can tell me what it is. An explanation aimed undergraduate physics level would be most helpful.

References:

1. K.S. Novoselov et al, *Two-Dimensional Gas of Massless Dirac Fermions in Graphene,* [Nature 438 (2005) 197](http://www.dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature04233), [arXiv:cond-mat/0509330](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0509330).

Comment: I was unable to find the typo in [the paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0509330) (I also linked it in your question). Do you have a different version or something?

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): In general, it is not the purpose of Phys.SE to expose all typos of the literature. Is there any physics argument in the text that support that it is more than a typo?

Comment: @Danu Changed the link to Nature's website as that is the version I have access to. If you can access it just Ctrl-f for 'grapheme'. The sentence is in the second paragraph.

Comment: @Qmechanic Only that the word is also found in one of the citations. Unfortunately I cannot access that citation.

Comment: Maybe a "grapheme" is a graphical meme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer won't be very long, because there's not all too much to say: It's a typo. This is clear from the context:

1. The sentence describes graphe**n**e, as witnessed by the words "single layer", which is the characteristic property of graphe**n**e.
2. The sentence occurs in a paper on graphe**n**e.
3. The 'n' is found next to the 'm' on most keyboards.

Comment: @Jekowl As a nanotechnology student, I have never heard of grapheMe.

Comment: @user46147 as an amateur language nut, I have: roughly speaking, it's a written character such as a letter or numeral.

Comment: and it's really would be no stranger than standard chemistry nomenclature like alkene/alkane